# Prove that $2^x < \prod_{p\le x} p < (13/4)^x$ for sufficiently large x

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, contest-math, analytic-number-theory

Prove that $2^x < \prod_{p\le x} p < (13/4)^x$ for sufficiently large x. Here $p$ is prime.

---

So if we take logs we need to show for sufficiently large x, $x\log 2 < \sum_{p\le x}\log p < x\log(13/4)$. Also according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial

Asymptotically, primorials ''p<sub>n</sub>#'' grow according to:

$p_n\# = e^{(1 + o(1)) n \log n}$

where $o(\cdot)$ is the little o notation.

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156509/product-of-all-prime-numbers-upto-some-prime-p.

Comment: ...or you may use $\sum_{k=1}^n \log p_n = \int_2^n \log k\;  d\pi(k)$ and put in your favorite representation for $\pi(x)$. See here http://math.stackexchange.com/a/174769 ...

Comment: why is this [tag:contest-math]?

Comment: Because the difficulty level of this problem is at least contest-math level, yet it's easy to understand.

Comment: I guess that it's "contest-math" because it came from a math contest
and thus calls for an elementary proof along the lines of Čebyšev's method (see e.g. http://www.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M259.02/chebi.pdf ).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chebyshev: Proof $\prod \limits\_{p \leq 2k}{\;} p > 2^k$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95766/chebyshev-proof-prod-limits-p-leq-2k-p-2k)

Comment: See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33980/how-to-prove-chebyshevs-result-sum-p-leq-n-frac-log-pp-sim-log-n-a/33995#33995 and this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95766/chebyshev-proof-prod-limits-p-leq-2k-p-2k/95783#95783

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Rosser and Schoenfeld](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-6/issue-1/Approximate-formulas-for-some-functions-of-prime-numbers/10.1215/ijm/1255631807.full) prove, in their Theorem 4, that
$$
x\left(1-\frac{1}{2 \log x}\right) < \vartheta(x) < x \left( 1+\frac{1}{2 \log x} \right)
$$
for $x\ge 563$, where
$$
\vartheta(x) =\sum_{p\le x} \log p.$$

This yields your required bounds.